# Send DynamoDB events to Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-pinpoint, amazon-dynamodb

I have a web app with a serverless backend using `API Gateway`, `Lambda` and `DynamoDB`. In the app, a user can create/delete items. I want to use Pinpoint to know the total number of items created or deleted.

Right now, when a user creates/deletes a new item, a lambda function is triggered and I get the event, however, I have no idea about how to pass it to Pinpoint. I checked the docs and `Pinpoint.putEvents` seems like the solution but I can't find any example or reference where this is done

Do you have any resource for this scenario or any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what language is your lambda in? You can use e.g. the AWS SDK to make a putEvents call to Pinpoint. For python see the boto3 documentation at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pinpoint.html#Pinpoint.Client.put_events

Comment: @Korgen I am using JS. But I will look at the docs you posted. Thanks